# Can I turn a computer into a network switch/router?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, bridge, windows-10

I have 3 computers that I want to connect via 100Gbe network connections. 2 of the computers/servers are equipped with Mellanox ConnectX-4 single adapters and one computer is equipped with a dual ConnectX-4 adapter that has two QSFP28 connectors. The purpose of the latter computer is to function as storage server. So far I connect the other two machines each directly with the storage server and it works.

However, the two machines that connect to the storage server cannot communicate with each other. My question is: Can I configure the storage server, which houses the dual ConnectX-4 adapter and which connects to each of the two machines directly, in a way so that the two machines can communicate with each other via some sort of bridge on the storage server? Obviously I still want each of the machine to have access to the storage server but also want each of the machines to be able to communicate with each other.

My OS is Windows 10 for Workstatations for all machines but I am willing to consider a full-fledged Windows Server OS if it solves my problem but W10fWS does not.

Edit: This is not a data center or production environment but for experimental purpose. 100G switches are incredibly expensive for a small lab environment and only 3 machines hence my wanting to solve this issue on the software side.

Comment: It's possible, but why bother?  Switches are cheap.  Trying to make Win10 or Win Server function as a switch isn't the way to go.

Comment: 100G switches are not cheap, they start at USD 5000 and go into the tens of thousands. I would appreciate if you could re-read the question and possibly remove the "hold" as I clearly mentioned I am dealing with a 100Gbe network.And I think it becomes apparent that I am not dealing with a data center issue in which case your latter point makes sense. But I will add an edit to make this clear.

Comment: I misread the question, but trying to get 100Gb between 3 Win10 machines still isn't the way to go.

Comment: You can bridge network connections in Windows 10 and create... a network bridge.

Comment: THe problem is that 100g switches are expensive because it takes a LOT of power to even switch 100g. You can not expect a computer to "just do it" on the side. Yes, you can do it - it is trivial, as basically you ask us to teach you the basics of how to set up a bridge in windows, which somehow actually is in the documentation. But for 100g - NO WAY if you want to even come close to the performance it can give you.

Comment: @TomTom, do you have any links or numbers to back up that assertion? Not that I disbelieve but I always prefer to see numbers. I checked but could not even find performance tests for 10Gb, 25Gb, 40Gb bandwidths.

Comment: Nope. See, the abuse of computers as high perforamcne swithces is abuse and rarely done - thus noone really does performance tests. The best you get here is some stuff from Azure which go into that - there actually IS a benefit, if you run a special linux kernel and are willing to run the processors in endless loops (i.e. not event).

Comment: Well, I have the hardware available hence I might as well try it out. Again, this is not for a production environment nor is it intended for deployment in any data center or larger network but simply a quick and dirty solution to connect three workstations/servers.